# How to get a user's default language?

Tags: sql-server

In SQL Server, [sp_defaultlanguage](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Aa259642(v=SQL.80).aspx) sets a user's default language, but how does one get the existing value (for an arbitrary user)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
SELECT default_language_name
FROM sys.server_principals
WHERE name = ?
```

Answer (score 2):

Use global variable @@LANGUAGE for current user

```
SELECT @@LANGUAGE
```

or use sys.sql_logins:

```
SELECT default_language_name
FROM sys.sql_logins
WHERE name = ?
```

Comment: This retrieves the value for the current user, but I needed this for an arbitrary user. I'll clarify the question.